# How frequently can a particular MySQL row be updated before hitting lock contention?

Tags: mysql

This is about row updates, not row insertion. Are there any perf tests or even ballpark estimates for updates/sec before hitting contention issues? I've looked on the web for examples and haven't really found much. Thanks!

Comment: Too many variables involved. Disk speed, memory allocated, indexes present AND affected, size of updates ....

Comment: two simultaneous updates will hit lock, frequency impacts only time needed to get lock

Answer (score 0):

Lock contention has nothing to do with the frequency of updates.

You can get lock contention if just two transactions update the same row (really the same index). This can happen even if these are the only two updates you run in the whole day. I can produce an example of lock contention on my local MySQL instance on my laptop, which is otherwise idle.

Likewise, you could run a single-threaded workload that updates a row thousands of times per second (assuming your server has enough horsepower to sustain that load), and *never* hit lock contention, because a single thread will not be in contention with itself.

Your question is like asking how fast do you need drive your automobile on a highway before you get stopped in a traffic jam. The two have nothing to do with each other.